# Getting data in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have two classes: MoviiesPageActivity (extends FragmentActivity) and MoviesPageTab1 (extends Fragment). I need to send data from one to another. How can I get the data in the second sent from the first?

**MoviesPageActivity**

```
 public class MoviesPageActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

        private ViewPager viewPager;
        private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
        private ActionBar actionBar;
        // Tab titles
        private String[] tabs = { "About movie", "Ratings", "Crew" };

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.movies_page);

            // Initilization
            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            actionBar = getActionBar();
            mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

            // Getting contents
            Intent intentGet = getIntent();
            String id = intentGet.getStringExtra("id");
            MovieStruct info = new MovieStruct();
            info = getArrInfo(id);

            // Adding contents
                    // For example, how send string id?

            // Adding Tabs
            for (String tab_name : tabs) {
                actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
            }


            //on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    // on changing the page
                    // make respected tab selected
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                    //nothing
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                    //nothing
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**MoviesPageTab1**

```
public class MoviesPageTab1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container, false);

        // How can I get string id here?

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: The easiest way it to send the values using Arguments in Fragments. This is nothing but modified version of intent.putExtra();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution 1:

Create object of `MoviesPageTab1` and send and receive the data with the help of setter and getter functions.

## Solution 2:

Use [setArguments()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments(android.os.Bundle)) method while loading the `MoviesPageTab1` fragment.

## Solution 3:

Use [Callbacks](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) for communication between the Fragment and its parent Activity.

Answer (score 0):

I have already answered that kind of question before, but as none of the answers was accepted, I would simply post a link to my answer. [In short: use callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22507002/1900071)

PS. The link above directs you to a fully working example of Activity to Fragment communication, based on the technique proposed by [official dev docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)