# How to access an object from an activity into a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to pass an object from an activity to a fragment. My activity has a tabs layout consisting of view pager and four fragments.

I have an object in the activity which I want to access it in all the fragments.

I tried to create a getMethod in activity and then access the object in fragment. But it's not working, all the ways I am getting the object as a null.

Activity:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    toolbar.setTitle("Profile");

    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp);


    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            finish();

        }
    });

    GetProfileAsyncTask task = new GetProfileAsyncTask(ProfileActivity.this,this,profile);

   // task.setTaskCompletedListener(this);

    task.execute("sid");

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),mTitles,mNumbOfTabs);

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mTabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
    mTabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tab_scroll_color);
        }
    });
    mTabs.setViewPager( mViewPager);


}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public JSONObject getProfile(){
    return this.profile;
}
@Override
public void doInBackground() {

}

@Override
public void doPostExecute(JSONObject response) {
    profile = response;
    Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,
            "Finish", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I want to pass profile object to fragment.

Fragment:

```
public class BasicInformationFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{

    EditText email,pass,mobile,code;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    JSONObject profile;
    String userUsername,password,mobileNumber,emailId;
    private ProfileActivity myActivity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_basic_information,
                container, false);
      //  try{



    ((ProfileActivity)getActivity()).getProfile();

          //  password = profile.getString("userPassword");
         //   mobileNumber = profile.getString("userMobileNo");
         //   emailId = profile.getString("userEmailid");



            email = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_email);
            pass = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_pass);
            mobile = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_mobile);
            code = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_code);


         //   email.setText(emailId);
         //   pass.setText(password);
          //  mobile.setText(mobileNumber);


       // }


     //   catch (JSONException e)
     //   {}
        return view;
    }
```

What is going wrong here? Please help. Thank you..

Basically I want to access objects of Activity in Fragment. If there is another approach let me know. thanks

Comment: What error you are getting while calling `((ProfileActivity) getActivity()).getProfile();`

Comment: no error. When I do debug the object is null. @Lawrance

Comment: in Activity are you getting profile object after completion of AsyncTask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are running Async Task in Activity. Means You can run the Async Task in Fragment too. And get the Result from callback in fragment.

Comment: I need to to access this object in every fragment. So the thought was to run asyncTask in n activity and access the object from activity in every fragment. @Avinash8989

Comment: Send Data Using Callback or Interface. Call the Callback Interface in all the Fragment. And Fire it from on Post. Attach the Callback in Fragment in OnAttach.

Search for How to send data from Activity to Fragment using Callback.

Visit Developer Site for More info.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

Answer (score 0):

Override onAttched() Method its give activity object in some time getActivity() method gives null reference of activity.

```
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
  super.onAttach(activity);
  this.mActivity = activity;
  JSONObject mObject =((ProfileActivity)getActivity()).getProfile();
}
```

Comment: still its null. @Divyesh Boda

Comment: In Activity Class i can not find out where profile JSONObject is assign. make sure you get object in fragment before profile object is assign of not

Comment: it is assigned in doPostExecue method in profile activity. @Divyesh Boda

Comment: make sure in doPostExecue method JSONObject you assign in profile object is not null reference

Comment: I have checked it. It is not null. @ Divyesh Boda

Comment: But in you code taskListener code put in comment just remove this comment

// task.setTaskCompletedListener(this);

Answer (score 0):

create a separate common class for JSON Object.and assign the value from the main activity it self..i.e,

```
public class Common{
    public static JSONObject commonprofileobject;
}
```

then assign value from activity..
`Common.commonprofileobject=XXXX;`
then u can access it from fragment

Comment: How will I get object of profile activity here in common class?@VYSHAK M

Comment: U must assign the value in ur activity before u are handling the fragment page actions..

Comment: in ur postexecution method u must assign the value `Common.commonprofileobject=response;` then in the fragment class get this value `profile=Common.commonprofileobject;`

Comment: it still returns null. @VYSHAK M

Comment: Can u comment the whole profile activity Code? SO that i can check

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to use profile object before this AsyncTask (below
        piece of code) returns. one of the thing u can do is to use callbacks so 
        that Activity will notify your fragment when the asnyctask returns.

```
task.setTaskCompletedListener(new GetProfileAsyncTask.OnTaskCompleted() {
    public void onTaskCompleted(JSONObject response) {

        profile = response;

    }
});
```

For More details please visit this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) or you could also refer to the approved answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22507002/2078074).

Answer (score 0):

for this add a basefragment class in your project and extend your fragment from basefragment class

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment{

private Activity activity;
public ProgressDialog prog = null;

private MainActivity parent;
private final String TAG = "";//MainActivity.class.getName().toString();

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.activity = activity;
    setParent(getHomeActivity());
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

public MainActivity getHomeActivity() {
    try {
        return (MainActivity) activity;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}

public MainActivity getParent() {
    return parent;
}
public void setParent(MainActivity parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}
}
```

for example extends the fragment like this and use getparent method in fragment to access your object from mainactivity

```
public class BasicInformationFragment extends BaseFragment {

EditText email, pass, mobile, code;
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
JSONObject profile;
String userUsername, password, mobileNumber, emailId;
private ProfileActivity myActivity;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getParent().yourobjectnametoaccess;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Static instance of Activity in your 'ProfileActivity' class

```
public static ProfileActivity instance;

public static ProfileActivity getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new ProfileActivity ();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Then write your method which is having JSON object

```
public JSONObject getProfile(){
return this.profile;
}
```

Now in your fragment inside 'onCreateView' method you can directly access your JSON object 'getProfile' method following way

```
JSONObject profileObj = ProfileActivity .getInstance().getProfile();
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: it returns null. @Reena

Comment: Can you please share you log cat? You have to register your activity instance in oncreate method of activity. 

instance = this;

Comment: can you please share your logcat :(